# MongoDB performance recommendation

Tags: json, database, mongodb, performance, nosql

I have a project that I am working on and I was wondering what's the best approach to map out this schema looking at it from a performance perspective.

This is how my data looks like

`{
  "description": "this is a payment description",
  "payment": {
    "amount": 2000,
    "type": "type1",
    "gateway": "gateway1"
  }
}`

What I want to do is be able to calculate the sum of the **amount** filtered by any of the keys supplied in the JSON.

These are the schema's I had in mind.

**SCHEMA 1**

`{
  "description": "this is a payment description",
  "payment": {
    "amount": 2000,
    "type": "type1",
    "gateway": "gateway1"
  }
}`

**SCHEMA 2**

`{
  "description": "this is a payment description",
  "payment_amount": 2000,
  "payment_type": "type1",
  "payment_gateway": "gateway1"
}`

Assuming the data gets into a million records, does the performance(in terms of retrieval time) get better when I flatten the JSON and save each as a top-level property or it doesn't matter how nested the object is?

Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB is document-oriented database, then schema1 is the way to go. Otherwise would be better to call it "flatten-oriented" database! Having a structure with nested object make more easy to work for example with one line of code you can unload "payment: -1" from your find() query and save data that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, both the schema designs shown above look fine.

Too many levels of nesting in a document causes unnecessary trouble in querying and updating the document. So use nesting only where its required and actually makes sense otherwise a flat document structure is perfectly fine.

In terms of performance, the difference will be hardly noticeable for both these schema designs, Schema 1 would just consume a little more space then Schema 2.

Answer (score 0):

Schema one since Mongo is built for handling such document structures.

If you're keen on simplicity then use schema 2 because it will make the filtering simple incase you are to convertt each record to some class in whichever language.(thanks for this Steve)